# Lower semi-continuity of integration

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, integral-operators

I've found many papers characterizing the weak lower semi-continuity of
$$
\Phi(u)\triangleq \int_{x \in \Omega} f(x,u(x))\,dx,
$$
on $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Are there any results with regards to the same statement with $\Omega$ being all of $\mathbb{R}^d$ itself?

Here $f$ is a non-negative, Borel measurable function, which is convex in its second variable for a.e. one of its first variagbles.

Comment: You should clarify what statement you have in mind. For example $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|u|^2$ is (sequentially) weakly lower semicontinuous since the norm is (sequentially) weakly lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Aren't sequential weak lower-semi-continuity and weak lower-semi-continuity the same in a Hilbert space?

Comment: What are you assuming about $f$?  If it's continuous in the second variable and nonnegative then this is just Fatou's lemma.  And if it's not continuous then I don't see why you would expect any semicontinuity at all.

Comment: Even under those assumptions, whouldn't that only give strong lower semi continuity which is less than weak lower semi continuity?

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed "weak".  But Borel is certainly not enough; take $f(x,u) = 1_{[0,1]}(u)$ and $u_n = 1+1/n$.

Comment: True, in that case the most I can assume is that $f$ is convex in its second variable for almost-every $x$ (I made the update, as I was trying for a weaker result)

Comment: Did you check the book by Fonseca and Leoni?

Comment: I don;t know this book.  What is it called?